# Memory leak detection on Universal Windows Platform

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, windows-10-universal

In my application, I want C++ runtime library to automatically detect memory leaks. In Win32 application, this works perfectly well by adding the following code:

```
#if defined(_DEBUG) || defined(DEBUG)
    _CrtSetDbgFlag( _CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF | _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF );
#endif
```

In Universal Windows Application, this unfortunately has no effect. I tried to call `_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks()` manually, but I can't really find appropriate place to do this. I would appreciate any suggestions. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Win32 and UWP apps are totally different types of applications so it may happen that some library works on either of the platform.

You can check the memory leaks by running inbuilt memory usage and performance diagnostic tools in Visual Studio. You can collect different memory snapshots and compare them in Memory Tool. Kindly go through [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt125494.aspx) and [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2015/07/20/performance-and-diagnostic-tools-in-visual-studio-2015/) for more technical briefing and implementation.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but I do not think that answers my question. In Win32 applications, memory leaks can be automatically detected using c++ runtime library. I was wondering if the same is possible in UWP application.